# How do I get rid of "Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget" error?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I can't avoid the "Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget" error. The code below works - I want to be able to drop a draggable widget onto a dragTarget in the bottomSheet, but also want the widget to be draggable in the body.

The code works fine in the emulator, but when the draggable is accepted on the dragTarget, the error is flagged up in the console.

Is there something obvious that I'm doing wrong?

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

bool isAccepted = false;
DragMe niceBox = new DragMe('Hello', 50.0, 100.0, Colors.green);
DragMe nastyBox = new DragMe('Yucky', 150.0, 100.0, Colors.brown[300]);
TargetBox targetBox = new TargetBox();
MyDragTarget myDragTarget = new MyDragTarget();
const kTopSpace = 96; // Height of Appbar plus the icon bar above

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData( fontFamily: 'PressStart'),
      home: MyHomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomeScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  createState() => MyHomeScreenState();
}

class MyHomeScreenState extends State<MyHomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.red[100],
      appBar: AppBar(
        toolbarHeight: 70.0,
        title: Center(child: Text('My brain hurts')),
        backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
      ),
      body: Stack(children: [niceBox, nastyBox]),
      bottomSheet: Container(
        color: Colors.lightBlue,
        height: 100.0,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: [myDragTarget],
        ),
      ),
    );
  } // End build()
} // End class MyHomeScreenState

class DragMe extends StatefulWidget {
  DragMe(this.myText, this.xPos, this.yPos, this.myColor);
  final String myText;
  double xPos;
  double yPos;
  final Color myColor;

  @override
  _DragMeState createState() => _DragMeState();
}

class _DragMeState extends State<DragMe> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Positioned(
      left: widget.xPos,
      top: widget.yPos,
      // left: widget.xPos,
      // top: widget.yPos,
      child: Draggable(
        data: widget.myText,
        feedback: Container(height: 50, width: 70, color: Colors.grey),
        childWhenDragging: Container(),
        onDragStarted: () {},
        onDragEnd: (details) {
          setState(() {
            widget.xPos = details.offset.dx;
            widget.yPos = details.offset.dy - kTopSpace;
          });
        },
        onDragCompleted: () {},
        onDraggableCanceled: (velocity, offset) {},
        child: Container(
          child: Center(child: Text(widget.myText)),
          color: widget.myColor,
          height: 50,
          width: 70,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyDragTarget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DragTarget<String>(
      builder: (context, List<String> acceptedData, rejectedData) {
        if (isAccepted) {
          return niceBox;
        } else {
          return targetBox;
        }
      },
      onWillAccept: (data) {
        if (data == 'Hello') {
          isAccepted = true;
          return true;
        } else {
          isAccepted = false;
          return false;
        }
      },
      onAccept: (strData) {},
      onLeave: (strData) {
        return true;
      },
      onMove: (moveData) {
        return true;
      },
      onAcceptWithDetails: (data) {},
    );
  }
}

class TargetBox extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: Center(child: Text('Drop Here')),
        color: Colors.yellow,
        height: 50.0,
        width: 100.0);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your stack doesn't have any maximum bounds it can keep itself to. What you want to do is wrap `Stack` into a `SizedBox` or `Container` with the width and height of your choice. If you want it to take all available space do it like this:

```dart
SizedBox(
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
  child: Stack(),
)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. I've wrapped the Stack, but if I monitor the console when you drop the Hello container onto the dragTarget, I still get the "Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget" error. The expanded error text says: "Usually, this means that the Positioned widget has the wrong ancestor RenderObjectWidget. Typically, Positioned widgets are placed directly inside Stack widgets. The offending Positioned is currently placed inside a MetaData widget.".  I'm stuck on trying to address this!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html) the `Positioned` widget must be a direct descendant of the `Stack`

> A Positioned widget must be a descendant of a Stack, and the path from the Positioned widget to its enclosing Stack must contain only StatelessWidgets or StatefulWidgets (not other kinds of widgets, like RenderObjectWidgets).

Since you have `Stack > DragMe > Positioned` it fails with that error.

You need to have

```
    Stack(children: [
        Positioned(...),
    ])
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've tried this to no avail. I've decided that using the Positioned widget is incompatible with the DragTarget, so will just have to work around it.